# LINQ : Convert anonymous type to another anonymous type C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to extend LINQ query based on some conditions.

Actually I am writing a dynamic search functionality where user can select any field and can search. Here if user selects a field that is not available in default LINQ query then I want to extend existing LINQ Query.

For Example

```cs
var query = 
    from tbl1 in context.Table1
    join tbl2 in context.Table2 on tble1.Id equals tble2.tble1Id
    where tble1.IsDeleted == false;
```

And If User Selects a field that cannot be searched in this above query then I want to extend "query" variable as below.

```cs
query = query
    .GroupJoin(context.table3, 
        a => new { contactId = a.contact.Id, formId = a.contact.FormIdFK }, 
        DynamicFieldData => new { contactId = DynamicFieldData.EntityIdFK, formId = DynamicFieldData.FormIdFK }, 
        (x, y) => new { a = x, DynamicFieldData = y })
    .SelectMany(x => x.DynamicFieldData.DefaultIfEmpty(),(x, y) => new { a = x.a, DynamicFieldData = y })
    .AsQueryable();
```

And At the end I can apply dynamic Where Claus on above finalized query.

But when I try to assign updated query to "query" variable it says.

*Errror : system.linq.iqueryable <some anonymous type 1 > cannot be implicitly converted to  system.linq.iqueryable <some anonymous type 2 >*

Comment: What is the purpose of the `AsQueryable`?

Comment: C# is a strongly typed language. `query` has a type (I am not sure what it is, your code creating `query` is invalid since it has no `select`). When you change the element type you can't assign it back to `query`, any more than you can do `var q = "this"; q = q.Length;`

Answer (score 1):

Usually I use the following pattern:

```cs
// apply join
var withOtherTable = 
    from q in query
    join t in context.table3 on ... equals ... into gj
    from t in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { q, t };

// apply filters
withOtherTable = withOtherTable.Where(x => x.t.SomeField == "some");

// back to original query
query = withOtherTable.Select(x => x.q);
```